# DOM event handling with ES6 class methods

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm not entirely certain whether or not StackOverflow is the correct place to bring this topic up, but I guess I'll be corrected if I'm wrong.

---

I'm asking myself, what is a "better practice" to deal with *DOM event handlers* within a prototype-chain (or ES6 "class").

Problems arise if you bind a method like:

```
node.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, false);
```

(full example below)

You obviously lose your `this` context when that method gets invoked. We can solve this issue by binding the context to that very method (`this.clickHandler.bind( this )`). The only problem in using this technique is, that `bind()` will return another function reference of course. That in turn means, you cannot just simply remove that handler by calling

```
node.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
```

because you're dealing with different functions. The only way that I could think of so far would be, to create that bound method before you attach it to the event and also store it in your `this` context variable:

```
this._boundClickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind( this );
node.addEventListener('click', this._boundClickHandler, false);
```

Yes this does the job, but it seems very ugly and not very intuitive. Are there better patterns to solve this kind of issues within an *ES6 class*?

```
class foo {
    constructor() {
        this._boundClickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind( this );
        document.body.addEventListener( 'click', this._boundClickHandler, false );
    }

    clickHandler( event ) {
        // do stuff
        document.body.removeEventListener( 'click', this._boundClickHandler );
    }
}
```

Comment: _"very ugly and not very intuitive"_ -- my thoughts on using class syntax. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 itself doesn't have the solution you'd like, but you can use ES7 Class Properties:

```
class foo {
    constructor() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, false );
    }

    clickHandler = event => {
        // do stuff
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
    }
}
```

clickHandler, being a fat-arrow function, has 'this' context bound to the class instance, which is exactly what you want

Comment: very nice. It also plays nicely together with async functions, all you need is the `transform-class-properties` babel plugin to just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the defaults options available in ES6 and return events:

```html
class foo {
  static defaults() {
    return {
      events: {
        "click .node_identifier": "nodeClick"
      }
    };
  }
  
  nodeClick(e) {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```