# bind a on click, use the method inside a class that generate the element

Tags: javascript

I have this class

```
function user(){
    this.create_user = function(){
        var $el = document.createElement('div');
        $el.classList.add('user');
        $el.innerHTML = '<a href="#">I am a user</a>';
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild($el);
    }
    this.sayMyName = function($name){
        alert($name);
    }

    return this.create_user();
}

var user = new user();
```

now is there a way I could use the method 'sayMyName' when click on the newly created element? tried

```
function user(){
    this.create_user = function(){
        var $el = document.createElement('div');
        $el.classList.add('user');
        $el.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onClick="this.sayMyName("jonas")">I am a user</a>';
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild($el);
    }
    this.sayMyName = function($name){
        alert($name);
    }

    return this.create_user();
}

var user = new user();
```

but unfortunately not working, any help, ideas please?

Comment: `$el.addEventListener('click', ()=> this.sayMyName("jonas"));`

Comment: @quirimmo you should add that as an answer, I tested it and it works, use this line instead of having an onclick attribute in the anchor tag.

Comment: @quirimmo ES6 arrow functions ftw! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOM event handling with ES6 class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957960/dom-event-handling-with-es6-class-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to use bind

```
  function user(){
        this.sayMyName = function($name){
            alert($name);
        }

        this.create_user = function(){
            var $el = document.createElement('div');
            $el.classList.add('user');
            $el.innerHTML = '<a href="#" >I am a user</a>';
            var link = ( $el.firstElementChild || $el.firstChild );
            link.addEventListener('click', this.sayMyName.bind(this, 'jonas') );
            document.querySelector('body').appendChild($el);
        }


        return this.create_user();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** The JavaScript attempt which will be more suitable (as told by a comment) would be to add a Listener as such:

```
$el.addEventListener('click', function() {
   //
});
// OR
$el.addEventListener('click', this.sayMyName());
```

Personally, I have had issue with these Listeners not working. If that happens with you make sure to place within this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   //
});
```

Comment: The question does not use a jquery element, so it should be `$el. addEventListener('click', function() { ... });`. Also, `$el.click(this.SayMyName());` would call the function directly and use the result as event listener (more clear in equivalent code `var listener = this.SayMyName(); $el.click(listener);`)

Comment: Fair enough, didn't think too much about that